# Question on the theorem that meromorphic functions in the extended complex plane are the rational functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a theorem in Stein's Complex Analysis book at page 87.

Theorem: The meromorphic functions in the extended complex plane are the rational functions.

It starts off by saying that there should be finitely many poles in f, denoted by $z_1,\dots,z_n$.

Then $f(z)=f_k(z)+g_k(z)$ where the first term is a principal part of $f$ at $z_k$ and the second term is a holomorphic function in some neighborhood of the pole $z_k$.  Also, $f(1/z)=\tilde{f}_\infty(z)+\tilde{g}_\infty(z)$ where the first term is the principal part of $f(1/z)$ at 0 and the second part is a holomorphic function in some neighborhood of the origin. Let $f_\infty(z)=\tilde{f}_\infty(1/z)$.

The writer then constructs a new function $H=f-f_\infty-\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k$ and claims that it is entire and bounded. It says that it is because if we subtract the principal part, the pole corresponding to that principal part becomes removable singularity. Q1. We have only one $f$ in $H$, and I don't understand why the above statement holds. Q2. Also, this implies that there are singularities in $H$, but by definition entire function should be defined in all of $\mathbb{C}$ so I don't understand why $H$ becomes entire function.

Lastly... the writer in the end notes that "because of this theorem, a rational function is determined up to a multiplicative constant by prescribing the locations and multiplicities of its zeros and poles."

I read a related post that asked about this but I don't quite understand what it means by "determined up to a multiplicative constant." Q3. Can you please explain what the writer says here?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are meromorphic with same zeros (each of same order) and same poles (each of same order) the there exists a constant $c$ such that $f=cg$.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand the last statement. I still have trouble understanding why it is implied by the given theorem.

Comment: All  poles and zeros of $\frac f g$ cancel and you get an entire function which is also analytic at $\infty$. By Liouvile's Theorem it is  a constant.